# wp_list_categories() by alphabet? (ex. only category titles that start with “A”)

Tags: order, categories

I have used this code

```
function show_categories_fn(){
    return wp_list_categories("echo=0&title_li");
}
add_shortcode('show_categories', 'show_categories_fn');
```

I got the category list but I need alphabetic letters shown here below:

- A Apple Arkansas
- B Bangkok Borat Bunghole
- C Cat Copper

Comment: Are you on wordpress.com ? (you tagged the question with it). I'm still not sure what you're after here: You need to order the category list in alphabetic order but also add the alphabet letters too in front and then show only titles that start with A?

Comment: You mean you need first character or first character with word list

Answer (score 1):

`wp_list_categories()` uses the [`Walker_Category`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L967) walker which [applies the `list_cats` filter](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1042), so a little PHP and:

```
function alpha_prefix_wpse_210205($cat) {
  $fl = substr($cat,0,1);
  $fl = strtoupper($fl);
  return $fl.' '.$cat;
}
add_filter('list_cats','alpha_prefix_wpse_210205');
```

You will want to apply the filter just before you need it and [remove it](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) afterwards.

```
function show_categories_fn(){
    add_filter('list_cats','alpha_prefix_wpse_210205');
    $lc = wp_list_categories("echo=0&title_li");
    remove_filter('list_cats','alpha_prefix_wpse_210205');
    return $lc;
}
add_shortcode('show_categories', 'show_categories_fn');
```